# Python normal distribution over a day

Tags: python, numpy, math, timestamp, modeling

I am trying to make a function in python that would receive a time object and return a number that belongs to a distribution over the day. I have the graph and some points that I would like to fit in the curve, but other than that I would like the function to be dependent only on time.

Does someone have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: [random.normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)

Comment: yes, but how can I make timestamp as the bottom x of the distribution?

Comment: Your question statement says that the timestamp is used to generate a random value. What do you mean by "bottom X"

Comment: @Mayra Let x = (timestamp minus previous midnight). I don't remember if arithmetic on timestamps is defined in Python; you might have to do something like timestamp.seconds(). I don't remember how to get the previous midnight, but I'm sure you can look it up.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog my function would use a time to generate a value which belongs to a curve gaussian, for example, I want the maximum value to be centered at 14:00 hs